# How do I move my 4 cards so they are aligned in a diamond shape?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I am having trouble moving 4 individual cards into my desired shape which is a diamond configuration. I've looked everywhere but cannot find a solution to this simple problem?

I have attached my HTML and CSS code as well as the design I want to achieve, more specifically the bottom four cards in the diamond shape.

[This is the design I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLzYP.jpg):

[image]

The cards are currently in a straight line from left to right because I've applied flex on them.

I would really appreciate help and advice on this as it's driving me crazy!

I have tried Flexbox and Grid but to no avail. I suspect I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please include the code you already have. Your layout could be achieved by a simple grid, but we need to know your HTML structure and how the dimensions of the cards are decided. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple layout that consists of 3 columns inside a flex container, this is what you need to do:

You need to create a main flex container, inside you will have **3 *divs*/columns - flex children**.

Then these columns will have the cards inside (the 2nd one will have 2 cards while the  1st and last just 1).

I created a quick example for you, you will just need to adapt the heights and widths as needed (and add your content and card styles)

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.column {
    margin: 0 10px;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.card {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the future I would advice you to provide any starting code you have tried, it'll make people's life easier and improve your chances to get answers.
Let me know in the comments if you have any questions, otherwise don't forget to mark answer as accepted.